# VBA - How to use a cell value to a range header table

Tags: vba, excel

I can't find a solution to do a - I think - simple think in VBA :

```
C14 = Sheets("PARAM").Range("B12").Value

Range("Categorie").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = C14
```

I have this to rename a table column.
C14 is equal to the B12 value which is "Category".
Now, I want to change language :

```
Range("Tableau2[[#Headers],[Category]]").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = C25
```

And I don't find how to replace '[Category]' by the variable C14 which contain "Category"...

Is it possible ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tesseted this yet. But it should work if you do it this way.

old:

```
Range("Tableau2[[#Headers],[Category]]").Select
```

new:

```
Range("Tableau2[[#Headers],[" & Sheets("PARAM").Range("B12 ").value & "]]").Select
```